# how to include directories inside JAR into the classpath at buildtime using ANT?

Tags: ant, jar, directory, classpath

I have a JAR in my lib folder of the project and trying to get the directory structure that contains property files on the classpath when building using ANT.  Any ideas how best to the get that structure on the classpath?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to load a properties file into your build using the [`property`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) task.

If this is the case, there are a couple of options.

First you could use the `url` form of the task, using a [jar url](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html):

```
<property url="jar:file:lib/my_jar.jar!/path/to/myfile.properties" />
```

Alternatively you could use the `resource` form, and specify the jar as the classpath:

```
<property resource="/path/to/myfile.properties" classpath="lib/my_jar.jar"/>
```

If it's something else you want to do rather than load the properties, look into [`javaresource`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#javaresource) - many tasks are able to take a resource as input so you should be able to find a way to do what you want.